# Cypress: How to pass if its() function DOES timeout

Tags: cypress

I have a test where I want to know that a window property is NOT set after an arbitrary timeout period.

So, in pseudo-code:

```js
cy.window().its('msg_1', {
  timeout: 3000
}).should.timeoutIn3000
```

In other words, the test passes if the 3000ms timeout is reached. If the window property `msg_1` turns up before 3000ms, the test should fail.

Is that possible? I am probably missing the obvious here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, following @EQQ's helpful reply I found the following works:

```
    // This will pass if it is not there
    cy.window().then(win => expect(win.msg_1).to.eq(undefined))

    // Wait for the timeout and test again
    cy.window().wait(3000).then(win => {
      expect(win.msg_1).to.eq(undefined)
    })
```

and as a custom command:

```
    /**
     * Use to test that a window property does NOT turn up
     * within the specified time period
     */
    Cypress.Commands.add("notIts", (prop, timeout) => {
      cy.window().then(win => expect(win[prop]).to.eq(undefined))
      cy.window().wait(timeout).then(win => {
        expect(win[prop]).to.eq(undefined)
      })
    });
```

used like:

```
    cy.notIts('msg_1', 3000)
```

Maybe "notIts" is not a good name for it but anyway, this works for me.

Thanks!
Murray

Answer (score 0):

The strategy might be test, wait, test again.

```
it('does not see the message', () => {

  cy.visit('http://example.com').then(win => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      win.msg_1 = 'hi'
    }, 1000)
    
  })

  cy.window().then(win => expect(win.msg_1).to.eq(undefined))  // passes
  cy.wait(3000)
  cy.window().then(win => expect(win.msg_1).to.eq(undefined))  // fails

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That helped. I found when I used that code Cypress did not wait. If I console logged it the second test ran immediately after the first. Looking at the docs it should have worked. However, see below for what I eventually did. Thanks again for your help, Murray.

Comment: Murray, you're doing something wrong, this does wait.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will go back and see what might have been the issue. I am using it within cypress-cucumber but I can't see how that would be an issue. What I was experiencing is that a a console log before and after the wait appeared together - no 3 sec delay for the second. Odd.

Comment: Commands like `cy.wait()` are asynchronous. All synchronous commands in the test (like the console.log's either side of the wait) run before commands are executed.